# Package {anyfontsize}: any size but not the default with Drop Cap

Tags: fontsize, lettrine, drop-cap

To "beautify" a text I want to use an enluminure as shown by [a French Wikibook](https://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Options_de_mise_en_forme_avanc%C3%A9es). But my text also needs the package {anyfontsize}.

With the following MWE, I get the message "Paragraph ended before anyfontsize@set was complete." and then some..

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{oldgerm}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\newcommand{\enluminure}[2]{\lettrine[lines=3]{\small \initfamily #1}{#2}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\enluminure{L}{orem ipsum dolor sit amet.} \lipsum[2-5] 
\end{document}
```

How can I use the enluminure AND the {anyfontsize} package?

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use `anyfontsize`, but it's not the point. If you want the initials to be smaller than the default, you can do as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{yinitas}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{yinitas}{m}{n}{%
<-> s*[.7] yinitas
}{}
\newcommand{\initfamily}{\usefont{U}{yinitas}{m}{n}}

\newcommand{\enluminure}[2]{\lettrine[lines=3]{\initfamily#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\enluminure{L}{orem ipsum dolor sit amet.} \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite cryptic. The first work-around is not to use the {anyfontsize} package, but this will give error in other parts of the text. So a better way to do it, not perfect though, is to replace the default font size option by [11pt] or [12pt]. Then the MWE will compile without error, it is *anyfontsize* but the default :-).

Probably somebody with a better knowledge of the font system will come with a better option.